# Scalar subquery contains more than one row

Tags: sql, h2

Im working with H2 database and wanted to move some data. For that I created the following Query:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET EMAIL = SELECT service.EMAIL
FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE AS service
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS customer ON service.ID = customer.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID;
```

When I now perform it in the H2 console I get the following error:

```
Scalar subquery contains more than one row; SQL statement:

UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET EMAIL = SELECT service.EMAIL
FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE AS service
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS customer ON service.ID = customer.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID [90053-192] 90053/90053 (Hilfe)
```

What is this error telling me?

**EDIT**

What I want to achiev with my query:

Actually every `CUSTOMER` has a `CUSTOMER_SERVICE`. And I simply want to move the `COLUMN EMAIL` from `CUSTOMER_SERVICE` to the `CUSTOMER` Table. for that I already added a email column to the user. I hoped to be able to do it with my query but obviously not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not syntactically valid (all subqueries must have parentheses around them).

What you are missing is a correlation clause.  I believe you want:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER c
    SET EMAIL = (SELECT cs.EMAIL
                 FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE s
                 WHERE s.ID = c.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID
                );
```

I don't know what this is supposed to be:  `[90053-192] 90053/90053 (Hilfe)`.

Comment: [90053-192] 90053/90053 (Hilfe) is H2's error code (https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html#c90053): SCALAR_SUBQUERY_CONTAINS_MORE_THAN_ONE_ROW (The error with code 90053 is thrown when a subquery that is used as a value contains more than one row).

Answer (score 3):

Your select query is returning more than one row. If you don't want it to, then you need to do something like an aggregate or LIMIT 1 or something similar.

Comment: But I want taht query to perform on every Customer that I have.

Answer (score 2):

Your sub-query for at least one of your customers has multiple email addresses.

You could `... (Select top 1 serverice.email ...`
Or        `... (Select max(serverice.email) ...`

```
Update Customer Set EMail=B.Email
 From  Customer A
 Join  (Select ID,max(EMail) as EMail From CUSTOMER_SERVICE Group By ID) B
   on  (A.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID = B.ID)
```

Comment: @Mulgard BINGO!

Comment: @Mulgard My first choice would be the max() option

Comment: @Mulgard If multiple emails, do you want to see them as a DISTINCT delimited string?

Comment: @Mulgard If multiple distinct emails, do you want the last one entered?

Comment: @Mulgard See updated answer ... Full Update Statement

Comment: @Mulgard See update.  A sub-query/join may be more efficient

Comment: `Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "UPDATE Customer SET EMAIL=B.EMAIL 
 FROM[*]  Customer A 
 JOIN  (SELECT ID,MAX(EMAIL) AS EMAIL FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE GROUP BY ID) B 
   ON  (A.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID = B.ID) "`

Comment: What is  [*]  after the FROM?

Comment: I have no idea. I guess it says that `FROM` is causing the syntax error but actually your query is valid SQL.

Comment: oh I found the syntax error. too easy so that we could not see it. there is a `SELECT` missing between `FROM` and `Customer` :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've spend a lot time with this error type (there shoudn't be duplicates in DB).
At last I've found problem via SQL with COUNT like this:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER
SET EMAIL = SELECT COUNT(service.EMAIL)
FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE AS service
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS customer ON service.ID = 
customer.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_ID;
```

And then select problem rows with `EMAIL!='1'`