# update using the resultset from CTE in H2

Tags: sql-update, h2, common-table-expression

I am trying to update a table using the resultset from CTE. With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409432/h2-update-with-join)

Will the query work if table_b is the result of CTE like this

```
With table_b as (select a_id from table_x)
update table_a a
set a.b_id = (select b.id from table_b b where b.a_id = a.id)
where a.id = (select b.a_id from table_b b where b.a_id = a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` needs to be selected too, otherwise `b.id` will not be found.

```sql
with table_b as (select id, a_id from table_x)
update table_a a
set a.b_id = (select b.id from table_b b where b.a_id = a.id)
where a.id = (select b.a_id from table_b b where b.a_id = a.id)
```

You should also consider the `MERGE` command instead of `UPDATE`, it could be more efficient.

```sql
with table_b as (select id, a_id from table_x)
merge into table_a using table_b on table_a.id = table_b.a_id
when matched then update set b_id = table_b.id;
```